# javax.servlet.ServletException: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/xml/sax/helpers/DefaultHandler

Tags: java, json, jersey, glassfish, jax-rs

I am getting a show-stopping error trying to obtain JSON output from a basic JAX-RS setup. I am trying Netbeans' Web Services wizards which has generated this default 'service' code:

```
package service;

import entities.Manufacturer;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.DELETE;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;


@Stateless
@Path("entities.manufacturer")
public class ManufacturerFacadeREST extends AbstractFacade<Manufacturer> {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "RestDemoPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    public ManufacturerFacadeREST() {
        super(Manufacturer.class);
    }

    @POST
    @Override
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public void create(Manufacturer entity) {
        super.create(entity);
    }

    @PUT
    @Path("{id}")
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public void edit(@PathParam("id") Integer id, Manufacturer entity) {
        super.edit(entity);
    }

    @DELETE
    @Path("{id}")
    public void remove(@PathParam("id") Integer id) {
        super.remove(super.find(id));
    }

    @GET
    @Path("{id}")
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public Manufacturer find(@PathParam("id") Integer id) {
        return super.find(id);
    }

    @GET
    @Override
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public List<Manufacturer> findAll() {
        return super.findAll();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("{from}/{to}")
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public List<Manufacturer> findRange(@PathParam("from") Integer from, @PathParam("to") Integer to) {
        return super.findRange(new int[]{from, to});
    }

    @GET
    @Path("count")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String countREST() {
        return String.valueOf(super.count());
    }

    @Override
    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }

}
```

The error is showing up when I remove the `@Produces` annotation for `MediaType.APPLICATION_XML` in the `findAll()` method to leave `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON` (I only want JSON output).

XML is fine - the JSON-only annotation raises a `HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error` with Java exception: `javax.servlet.ServletException: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/xml/sax/helpers/DefaultHandler` error.

Using GlassFish 4.1.1. Server log is:

```
Info:   EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150605-31e8258
Info:   /file:/home/lemon/code/java/Netbeans/RestDemo/build/web/WEB-INF/classes/_RestDemoPU login successful
Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[service.ApplicationConfig]: Servlet.service() for servlet service.ApplicationConfig threw exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler not found by org.eclipse.persistence.moxy [6]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1532)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:75)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1955)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.BeanValidationHelper.<clinit>(BeanValidationHelper.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBBeanValidator.isConstrainedObject(JAXBBeanValidator.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBBeanValidator.shouldValidate(JAXBBeanValidator.java:208)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBMarshaller.validateAndTransformIfNeeded(JAXBMarshaller.java:587)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBMarshaller.marshal(JAXBMarshaller.java:481)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.rs.MOXyJsonProvider.writeTo(MOXyJsonProvider.java:949)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.invokeWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:265)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:250)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.JsonWithPaddingInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(JsonWithPaddingInterceptor.java:106)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.java:86)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.writeTo(MessageBodyFactory.java:1130)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.writeResponse(ServerRuntime.java:683)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.processResponse(ServerRuntime.java:424)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:414)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:312)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:292)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1139)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:460)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:386)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:334)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Downgraded to Glassfish 4.1 from 4.1.1 solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug in GlassFish https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-21440 the bug is actually in EclipseLink and there is a workaround described in the GlassFish bug report above.

You could try upgrading to Payara Server where this bug is fixed.

Comment: Switching to Payara was a great idea

Comment: The link above is broken, moved to https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/glassfish/issues/21440

Answer (score 0):

Check your JDK version, use JDK 1.7 may OK.

Comment: Same result using JDK 1.7. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is a missing jar file ( jackson-module-jaxb-annotations ) in glashfish 4.1.1. You can download it from this link http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjacksonmodulejaxbannotations212jar.htm or google download jackson module jaxb annotations.
Then include it in C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.1.1\glassfish\modules director. you can rename the jar file by removing the version number. Restart glassfish and redeploy your app. It works for me that way